# “Fancy” as an adjective

Tags: traduction, anglais, sens

In two cases I seem to be unable to find  the right translation for *fancy* into French.

- *A fancy camera*
- *A fancy hotel*

It mustn't be so hard to understand but I'm quite hazy about what's meant there and just feel so stupid.

Answer (score 10):

*Fancy* is one of those words which doesn't have only one or even a few equivalents in French. Its translation depends a lot on the word it qualifies and the context. In your cases, I would suggest the following:

- *Une caméra de pointe, (ultra)perfectionnée, sophistiquée*<sup>*</sup>, if it qualifies its performance, or it qualifies its looks, simply *une belle caméra*
- *Un hotel de luxe, luxueux, chic, élégant*

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>The French adjective *sophistiqué* in the sense of *sophisticated* is sometimes criticized as an anglicism, especially when characterizing technology advancements: “*Ces empl. de sophistiqué sont parfois critiqués par les puristes comme américanismes (ou anglicismes).*” ([TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sophistiqu%C3%A9))</sub>

Comment: Je n'ai jamais vu ni entendu critiquer *sophistiqué*.

Comment: @Evpok Le Grand Robert porte pourtant cette mention : «  (1968). Anglic. critiqué. Fig. Recherché, complexe, évolué, où interviennent des techniques de pointe. ». Je l'ai également entendu d'un professeur d'université. Tel que j'ai mentionné, son usage est *parfois* critiqué.

Comment: Effectivement, même le TLF apparemment.

Comment: _Élégant_ has for me an implied sobriety which is the opposite of _fancy_ which leans more over _tappe à l'œuil_.

Comment: @Un francophone: The correct spelling is "tape-à-l'oeil".

Answer (score 8):

It could be translated into something like *sophistiqué*, or perhaps *chic*.

Note the nuance between French and English here – in French, *sophistiqué* means unnecessarily elaborate (cf. *Dictionnaire Littré*) whereas in English it does not have this somewhat pejorative connotation. The adjective "fancy" means elaborate, but it also implies that the thing is decorative (and potentially non-functional) or meant to impress (i.e. elaborate beyond what is strictly necessary to make it useful). This is why I feel that *sophistiqué* could be a good translation.

Edit: And see @Micromégas' comment about "fancy" implying that the elaborateness of the object in question can even impair its function. The same idea is also conveyed by *sophistiqué* in the sense explained above.

Comment: I'm not sure.  In English it depends on register and context just as much as in French.  "Fancy", especially in western U.S. context implies over-elaborate and possibly non-functional sometimes.

Comment: @Micromégas Isn't that what I am saying about *sophistiqué*?

Comment: when you say that "fancy" means "elaborate beyone what is strictly necessary to make it useful" I think this lacks the perjorative sense of "elaborate so that it impairs function".

Comment: @Micromégas Sorry I didn't manage to convey that idea properly, I definitely meant that there is something pejorative about "fancy". I have  edited my answer accordingly and included your comment, I hope it is better.

Answer (score 8):

In more spoken french, "fancy" can be translated by "classe".

> Un hôtel classe, un restaurant classe, un manteau classe, un appartement classe, une soirée classe.

"Classe" is a mix between "classy", "luxury", "impressive". This does not fit the "fancy camera".

Answer (score 0):

Selon linguee et deepl on peut dire par exemple : *hôtel chic, hôtel raffiné, hôtel de luxe, hôtel haut de gamme, hôtel prestigieux, hôtel de charme* pour fancy hotel.